# Wildcard SSL setup. Invalid domain error message

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ssl

I am trying to setup a wildcard SSL (working on all subdomains). Both domains work fine: domain.com and www.domain.com. However, when I go to https://test.domain.com I get an invalid SSL/domain error message in my browser. Any idea how I can fix this?

Here is my virtual host settings. I am on Ubuntu/Apache2.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
 SSLEngine On
 SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/*.domain.com.crt
 SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/*.domain.com.key
 SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/*.domain.com.bundle.crt

 ServerName domain.com
 ServerAlias domain.com
 ServerAlias *.domain.com
 DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.com/public_html/
 ErrorLog /var/www/domain.com/logs/error.log
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName domain.com
 ServerAlias domain.com
 ServerAlias *.domain.com
 DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.com/public_html/
 ErrorLog /var/www/domain.com/logs/error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue! I had to purchase a wildcard SSL. Duh!